# How to modify incoming http request before it's parsed in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I've got an odd situation. A 3rd party software package is sending notifications to my REST webservice. Unfortunately it has a bug and the incoming HTTP requests are damaged to the point where they are not valid HTTP. Consequently Nodes HTTP parser refuses to accept them and closes the connection.

I have reported the bug but I don't know how long until there is a fix. It could be tomorrow, it could be never.

In the meantime I'd like to get it working anyway. Fortunately the damage is minor and easily repaired. If I could just replace 2 bytes in the incoming data before it gets to Nodes parser, all would be well in the world.

Unfortunately I can't seem to find a way to do it. Node always gets the first crack at the data and rejects it. I've gotten close - I can get the raw socket when it's opened and attach to its `"data"` event, thus at least seeing the data as it comes in, but it's already too late to modify it.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Worst case scenario you need to write your own "HTTP" server that fixes this. If the client is that broken, though, you really shouldn't be supporting it. Accommodating broken garbage clients is how your code base becomes cluttered with workarounds.

Comment: @tadman - The software does good things and it does it better than the alternatives we found. We haven't committed to it yet, but it's a strong contender. If only we could get past this hurdle...

Comment: If the software is actually good then they'll fix bugs quickly. If it's so busted that Node.js can't make sense of it, then it's really broken.

Comment: @tadman Realistically I think they'll fix it in a week or two. But they haven't promised anything. And there are deadlines coming up soon, so having it working, even with a workaround, would be preferable.

Comment: Do older versions of the software suffer from the same bug? Can you patch the software? I'd do everything other than add in a work-around as re-writing *valid* HTTP requests is easy, but broken ones are much harder to repair. You need to write your own low-level rewriter at the TCP level, or you need to find out how you can modify Express to deal with your broken content.

Comment: @tadman As I said, by sheer coincidence, the damage is actually dead easy to fix. Two known, fixed bytes in fixed positions are changed to 0. Anyway... you gave me an idea. I can write a sort of transparent proxy at the TCP socket level which corrects the damage. I'll try that tomorrow!